# Programmatically placing objects along Polygon Collider 2D

Tags: unity

In my game, I have Tiled "rooms" that were imported with Tiled2Unity.  All of these rooms have walls that are defined by Polygon Collider 2D objects.  In the event of a cave or dungeon, I'd like to implement torches.  Currently, I literally randomly place torches in each room, which is pretty good for lighting, but looks ridiculous.

After the room is added, rather than randomly place torches anywhere, I'd like to have them placed along the inside of the collider.  Is there a good way to make this happen?

Edit:

One of my first attempts was to get a list of all of the points in all colliders in a given room after it's instantiation.  I was starting with something like this.

```
GameObject _roomGO = 
   (GameObject)Instantiate(_room.gameObject, new Vector3 (-6.5f, 6.5f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);

List<PolygonCollider2D> _polyList =
   _roomGO.GetComponentsInChildren<PolygonCollider2D>().ToList();
```

However, this only gets the points from the first collider, whereas I need the points for all colliders in the room GameObject.  Additionally, I'm not sure how those points are stored in such a way that I could create a `List` or `Array` of lines, then evaluate those lines to determine which are inside the room (as opposed to along the outside, so nothing in the set [(x,0),(x,-13),(0,y),(13,y)].

Once I had a list of lines that weren't part of that set, I could choose a point on the line and drop in a torch.

Edit2 - images:

[image]
[image]

Edit 3:

Thank to @SP., I've used some of his code as shown here:

```
        if (_torches)
    {
        Transform _roomGOLayer = _roomGO.transform;
        int numTorch = rndObjects.Next(2,4);

        List<PolygonCollider2D> _polyList = _roomGO.GetComponentsInChildren<PolygonCollider2D>().ToList();

        foreach (PolygonCollider2D polCol in _polyList)   
        {
            foreach (Vector2 point in polCol.GetPath(0))
            {
                Debug.Log(point.x +" : "+ point.y);//you will be using these values

                GameObject _to = Instantiate(_torch, new Vector2(point.x, point.y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                _to.transform.parent = _roomGOLayer;
                _to.transform.position = _to.transform.parent.transform.position + new Vector3 (point.x, point.y, 0f);
            }
        }
    }
```

The biggest problem I'm having up front is that _polyList is only getting the first collider definition.  I think if I could solve that, I'd be in good shape.

[image]

Comment: Can you include an image of a typical case, showing the shapes of the colliders? (And where you'd ideally like the torches placed) There's a few ways this could be set up, so seeing what you've got so far will help clarify what next steps are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the elements of the paths. Then spawn torch there. Store them as `Vector2`. Very simple implementation below.

```
public GameObject mSphere;
PolygonCollider2D polCol;

void Start ()
{
    polCol = GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();

    foreach (Vector2 point in polCol.GetPath(0))//Implemented on outer path only, you will need multiple paths
    {
        Debug.Log(point.x +" : "+ point.y);//you will be using these values

        Instantiate(mSphere, new Vector2(point.x, point.y), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

If you get the list of colliders, so you have the points of them as well.

Use {(x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2} for determining the midpoint between (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) as well as next points.

Comment: Awesome answer and example - thank you. I'll try this tomorrow and probably will promote your answer unless someone else has something to offer.

Comment: This is a good start, but I'm having trouble capturing all of the colliders in a single room.  _polyList is only coming back with the first set.

Comment: [GetPath(0)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.GetPath.html) is just one (circular) path. You have to iterate for all the paths(GetPath(1/2/3 and so on) ) of one polygon collider. I think your `_polyList` is fine. Check with `Debug.Log()`.

Comment: `_polyList` appears to only be getting Element 0 from my list of nine paths when I debug.  Eventually, I'll need to randomize it a bit as I don't want *every* point to receive a torch object, but for now I'd be happy to have one dropped on every point in all colliders to start with lol.

Comment: Scratch that - I was able to loop it.  But is there an easy way to place it on a line between those points?  I guess I'm unsure how the point order creates lines in each collider.

Comment: You may need to store the midpoints as well for overall random point selection.

Comment: Any suggestions on that front?  Most of my core C# experience is far outside the realm of anything graphical - it's primarily number crunching and data generation.

Comment: When you have (x, y) pair of all points in a list, you just need to run a mid-point calculator using the tiny math I added later in the answer. (x1,y1) and (x2, y2) give you mid point of first line, then (x2, y2) and (x3, y3) gives you the mid point of second line and so on. You take two pair from list and store the calculated value/midpoint in an array or other data structure. It's the same math determining mid point of a line or between two coordinates. Then you run a random selection on the array of the midpoints putting `0 to array length` as random range.

Comment: `Random.Range(0, arrayLength)` is max exclusive for being a integer array.

Comment: Ah sorry - let me rephrase.  How do I know I'm getting vertices whose midpoints are not inside the geometry?  For instance, in your image, I don't ever want to place an object on the midpoint of a line extending between the outer and inner edges of the wall.

Comment: In your case, there may be two easy solutions. Optimize your colliders to one main circular path. That way you apply over points or aligned with it. Another way is to make sure one point is not being used more than twice to calculate mid points. That will rule out inter geometry midpoints. If your case is precision intense [this will help for sure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon).